# Making a program act as a web-browser

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, post, get

Normally to login to a web-portal we use a web-browser to fill in the credentials and then log in. Is there any way I can make my java program act as a web-browser, so that I am directly able to log in via my java program?

```
Java program/web-browser-----credentials-----> server ----authenticated---> success message
```

Comment: Generally, I use HttpClient for Apache, but there are possibly other choices which don't require such a large number of 3rd party libraries, you should try and see what you can do with something like URL and the URLConnection classes first

Comment: It can be done using only the included Java APIs since cookies etc are supported. It's probably more complicated than it needs to be though. Take a look at [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). It's a project aimed at browser automation.

Comment: Lots of ways, generally they involve writing a HTTP client (which is another way of saying a web browser).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Could you guide me to a tutorial?

Comment: @SuhailGupta *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an HttpClient from Apache Commons. See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Comment: There is also [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) which doesn't require any (nice as the apache libraries are) third party libraries.